# How to fill color below rectangular function in gnuplot?

Tags: gnuplot

I am searching for a long time on the net. But no use. Please help or try to give some ideas how to achieve this.

I would like to plot the finite potential well for 1D Schrodinger equation and so I build the stepwise rectangular function first and then plot it with 'filledcurves below'. Here is my code:

```
Terminal type set to 'aqua'
gnuplot> set style fill transparent solid 0.5 noborder
gnuplot> set xrange [0:5]
gnuplot> set yrange [0:0.8]
gnuplot> p(x) = x<= 2? 0.5: x>= 3? 0.5: 0
gnuplot> plot p(x) w filledcurves below lc rgb "gray"
gnuplot> set samples 500
gnuplot> replot
```

I want the regions below 0.5 in [0:2]&[3:5] were all filled with gray color, and no color for (2,3) coz I set the value to 0.

and here's the plot I got, however, it's not the result that I was expecting.

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S6QiM.png)

I would be more than grateful for any ideas you provide. Big thanks!

Comment: Works fine for me (tested with 5.0.5, 5.0.0, 4.6.6), see https://i.stack.imgur.com/w5cGR.png

Comment: Hi Christoph, the regions I wanted to be filled were x = 0:2 and 2:3 coz I set y = 0.5 for these two regions

Comment: Or did I understand the command in a wrong way? I feel 'gnuplot> p(x) = x<= 2? 0.5: x>= 3? 0.5: 0' indicating that when x <= 2 or x>= 3, y = 0.5, otherwise y = 0

Comment: Yes, you are right. I was confused by the result you posted (with which version did you create that one?). Use `plot p(x) with filledcurves x1 lc rgb "gray"`: https://i.stack.imgur.com/K85k3.png

Answer (score 1):

Plotting `with filledcurves below` doesn't do what you need. You must give an explicite reference to the `x1` axis to get the desired result:

```
set style fill transparent solid 0.5 noborder
set xrange [0:5]
set yrange [0:0.8]
p(x) = x<= 2? 0.5: x>= 3? 0.5: 0
set samples 500
plot p(x) w filledcurves below x1 lc rgb "gray"
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I typed in the identical line and still got something weird. My result only has the right-hand side part looks like yours while the left part looks the same as before. Is it a problem of the version? I am using 5.0.5

Comment: Can you try a different terminal (wxt or qt)? I don't have the aqua terminal. The image in the answer was generated with qt.

Comment: I actually did not have wxt or qt, but changing terminal did solve the problem! Thanks a lot! :D